# How to open, append, delete append, and close a list of word rtf files with vbscript

Tags: text, vbscript, line, delete-file

I have some code to open, append some text, delete said text, then save and close an rtf document file with vbscript. Here is the code:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\box\test.rtf")
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.Font.Size = "10"
objSelection.InsertAfter Text:="Hello"

objSelection.Delete
objDoc.SaveAs ("C:\box\test.rtf")
objWord.Quit
```

However, I need to do this with a list of files, so I thought I had to use
a FileSysObject like:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

' Check that the strDirectory folder exists
If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
        (strDirectory & strFile, ForAppending, True)
        ' Writes strText every time you run this VBScript
        objTextFile.WriteLine (strText)
        'objTextFile.WriteLine (strBlankText)
        objTextFile.Close
    Next
```

etc...
Keep in mind I'm leaving out some of the inititalization variables code.

Is there a way to combine these two approaches to the problem so I can operate on the file and still loop through all the files or am I doing this wrong?

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can merge the 2 approaches - simply move the Word code into the loop, making sure to close the active document at the end of the iteration. I have added an if to check the file extension of the current file to make sure Word opens the correct file types. Also a bit to change the name of the output file so you don't overwrite

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    if objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.path) = "rtf" then
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile.path)
        Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
        objSelection.Font.Size = "10"
        objSelection.InsertAfter Text:="Hello"

        objSelection.Delete
        objDoc.SaveAs objFSO.BuildPath("C:\box", objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.path) & "-test.rtf")
        objDoc.Close
    end if
Next

objWord.Quit
```

You'll also need to include your variable initialisation code, but this should be a starting point.

[FileSystemObject reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)